# Define an equivalence relation on set $\mathbb R$ so that that the quotient set is identifiable with [0, 2)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

That is, that every equivalence class has exactly one representative in the set $[0,2)$ and every element of $[0,2)$ belongs to exactly one equivalence class.

This problem is translated to English from a textbook, and even in the original it's vague (to me at least) what exactly identifiable means formally, although I understand what is being asked. Nevertheless, here is the given solution:

> Let's define the function
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
>         x - \lfloor x \rfloor \quad & \text{if $\lfloor x \rfloor$ odd}\\
>         x - \lfloor x \rfloor+ 1 \quad & \text{if $\lfloor x \rfloor$ even}
>     \end{cases}$$
> Then, let's define the relation $\sim \subseteq\mathbb R \times \mathbb R $ with: $x \sim y$ iff $f(x) = f(y)$. It's easy to verify that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation which satisfies what is being asked.

I understand why such defined function works for this. My issue with it is that it's not convincing enough, or I'm missing something which makes it obviously convincing. How to proceed to make it more explicit that every element of [0,2) indeed belongs to exactly one  equivalence class $[a]_\sim$?

edit: Or simply said, how can we be sure that the image of $f(x)$ is the desired set $[0,2)$?

Comment: Parity does not make sense for real numbers that are not integers. Perhaps, you may have meant to say that $[x]$ is odd or even instead, but that still needs clarification. Does it mean the floor of $x$? Alternatively, you could instead define $x \sim y$ to simply mean that $x-y$ is an even integer.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I blindly copied their notation, but I interpreted it as floor (I guess they mean floor?). I corrected the conditions, thanks

Comment: @powerline think about it like this. If the problem asked you to do this, but the quotient needed to be $[0,1)$, then maybe this would be more intuitive. Namely $x\sim y$ if and only if $\{x\}=\{y\}$, i.e., the fractional parts agree. Recall that $\{x\}$ is just $x$ without the floor of $x$, so all that is needed here is to define the 'even floor' of a real number, $\lfloor x\rfloor_2$ which is just the largest \emph{even} integer smaller or equal than $x$. the \emph{even fractional part} $\{x\}_2:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor_2$ is what you want to build the equivalence around.